# How to make PHP change from slideshow to video player with pagination

Tags: php, jquery, video, slideshow, text-files

I'm completely new to creating dynamic pages - so for the moment, I am using txt files to manage my simple data! I'll explain my set up first. I have one php page - it gets data from two .txt files:

```
brief.txt: written content (title and supporting text) 

photos.txt: image file names.
```

I am using php pagination, and this changes the content in the php page by referring to the numbers I have used in the .txt file, here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
$data=file("brief.txt");
$pages=0;
foreach($data as $temp){
$x=explode("|",$temp);
if($x[0]>0){
$pages=$pages+1;
}
}
if($_GET['p']){
$page=$_GET['p'];
}
if($_GET['i']){
$index=$_GET['i'];
}
if($index == "p"){
$page=$page-1;
}
if($index == "n"){
$page=$page+1;
}
if($page < 1){
$page=1;
}
if($page > $pages){
$page=$pages;
} 
$line=$data[$page-1];
$fields=explode("|",$line);
?>
```

and this is an example of my text file

```
 brief.txt:
1|TITLE 1|Content goes here
2|TITLE 2|Content goes here

 photos.txt: 
1|imageone1.jpg
2|imagetwo1.jpg
```

Hopefully that all makes sense! Now, my problem is, I have a few video files. At the moment, the images load in a jquery slideshow. I would like to somehow have the script change, for example, when it makes page 3 with a video file it doesn't create the slideshow, but instead creates a video player and can load the url of my video that is placed in the txt file. The code I am using at the moment for the jquery slideshow is this:

```
 <?php
echo"
<div id='portfolioslider'><div class='slider'>";
$photos=file("photos.txt");
foreach($photos as $image){
$item=explode("|",$image);
if($item[0]==$fields[0]){
$photo=trim($item[1]);
echo"<div><img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' /></div>\n";
}
}
echo"</div></div>"?>
```

I would like the above code, to change similar to this when you go to a page with a video:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/23024550?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0"         width="1024" height="576" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

And if you go back or forward to a page which doesn't have a video, I would like it to change back to the original jquery slideshow...

Please can someone help me out with the necessary code I would need to make this work! I am very much a beginner coder :(

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Assuming I understand your logic's structure, and it's possible I missed something:

Perhaps, using a videos.txt to store videos, as opposed to putting both inside of photos.txt? Also, look into using a MySQL database for this.

And if you absolutely must use this manner of coding, I'd create a function that accepts a file name, and depending on the extension determines if it is a video or an image, thus dictating what content to load, and how.

Or, you can add an extra flag to your photos.txt file:

```
1|blah|1
2|blahblah|0
```

Where the third '1' means video, and a '0' means photo? It's your metadata, so you can dictate its structure.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do is just check to see if the current file is a picture or a video. The easiest way would be to look at the extension. Your videos are also stored in photos.txt, right? try something like this:

```
<?php
    $photos=file("photos.txt");

    // since you already know the page number, you can just skip to that index instead of looping through the entire file
    $item = explode("|",$photos[$page-1]);
    $photo = trim($item[1]);

    //lets see if it's a photo or a video
    if(substr($photo,-3) == 'jpg') {
        //echo out code for images here
    } else {
        //echo out code for video here
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried this, but i've kinda broken it now...I would really appreciate if you could help me out a little further... ^^;; http://pastie.org/2759776

Comment: Instead of having images for the slideshow together (eg. page 1 has 3 images and it displays 3 in the slideshow) it displays only one, and each page after in the pagination displays the other images from this page. For example, page 1 shows image 1 in the slideshow, page two shows image 2 that's meant to be in the slideshow of page 1, page 3 shows image 3 that's meant to be in the slideshow of page 1, etc etc. Hope that makes sense!